# Rotate spaceship to face given directional vector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have some spaceships spawned around a planet. I want to make them fly around this planet.

I also want to rotate them to the direction that they're flying in. Because at the moment, the prefabs just have their initial rotations.

I don't know, if `transform.RotateAround();` is the right one to take for this problem. `Transform.Rotate()` is not working.

So my question is, how can I make the spaceships fly around the planet and rotate to the direction they are flying?

Here's my code so far:

```
Transform planet;    // The planet to fly around
float speed = 5;         // The movementSpeed
Vector3 flyDirection;   // The direction, it flies around

void Start()
{
    planet = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Planet").transform;  // Get the transform of the planet

    Vector3[] directions = { Vector3.left, Vector3.right, Vector3.up, Vector3.down };    // The possible directions to fly
    flyDirection = directions[Random.Range(0, directions.Length)];           // Get a random fly direction
}

void Update()
{
    transform.RotateAround(planet.position, flyDirection, speed * Time.deltaTime);           // Fly around the planet 
    transform.Rotate(..);     // Rotate the Object to the fly direction
}
```

Comment: Er...to clarify, is `transform.RotateAround()` working for you, or is that not working as you want either?

Comment: Hey, i really don't know ... The Objects are flying around but they dont circle around the planet. They all fly randomly in the east ...

Answer (score 1):

**Moving the spacecraft**

At the moment, you don't seem to be supplying the correct arguments to `Transform.RotateAround()`. Specifically, the second argument should be the axis around which the rotation is performed, which in this case should be a vector perpendicular to the desired `flyDirection` and the vector between the ship/planet, and not `flyDirection` itself. We can get this easily using [`Vector3.Cross()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Cross.html):

```
void Update()
{
    // Calculating vector perpendicular to flyDirection and vector between ship/planet
    Vector3 rotationAxis = Vector3.Cross(flyDirection, transform.position - planet.position);
    transform.RotateAround(planet.position, rotationAxis, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    // ...
}
```

**Rotating the spacecraft**

A quick shortcut to setting the rotation of an object to face an arbitrary direction is to assign the value to its `transform.forward` attribute. In your case, you can simply supply `flyDirection` as the new `forward` vector to use:

```
void Update()
{
    // Calculating vector perpendicular to flyDirection and vector between ship/planet
    Vector3 rotationAxis = Vector3.Cross(flyDirection, transform.position - planet.position);
    transform.RotateAround(planet.position, rotationAxis, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    // Setting spacecraft to face flyDirection
    transform.forward = flyDirection;
}
```

If you need the specific quaternion value for this, or need the spacecraft's `transform.up` always point in a particular direction (eg. Normal to the planet's surface), then consider using [`Quaternion.LookRotation()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) to set the rotation instead.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Im sad this code did not work. The spaceships start to get stuck on the axis. I made a screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/qZ54g Now they can't move anymore.

Comment: @Garzec Hm, interesting. My guess is that it's an issue with how you're defining the available `directions` - those four directions align to the axes that the ships are getting stuck on (at that point, the vector between the ship and the planet basically becomes the same as `flyDirection`, causing the cross product to fail). Can you supply a GIF of how the ships behave until they get stuck?